# Javascript does'nt work in mvc (about checkboxlist change)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to get selected values of checkboxlist.I wanna send values to UrunList action.Each values will be saved in Viewbag.abc then Viewbag will be sent Create view (another view).But I can't get values from checkboxlist with javascript

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#urunsec').change(function () {
        var id=$('#urunsec').value();
        $ajax({
            url:'Fatura/UrunList',
            type:'POST',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function () {
                alert('suc');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('error')
            }

        })
    });
});
```

**UrunList View**

```
@foreach (BillApplication.Models.Urunler con in Model )
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               <input id="urunsec" type="checkbox" name="urunsec" value="@con.UrunId.ToString()" />
                <input name="urunsec" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
            <td>@con.UrunId</td>
            <td>@con.UrunAdi</td>
            <td>@con.UrunFiyat</td>
            <td>@con.AltkategoriId</td>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>

    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", new { idlist= @ViewBag.abc as List<String>})'" />

        </td>
    </tr>
```

**UrunList Action**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UrunList(string id)
    {
        this.UrunList(id);
        List<String> idlist = new List<String>();
        idlist.Add(id);
        ViewBag.abc= idlist;
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

**Create View**

```
<td><textarea id="txt_urunler" rows="2" cols="20" style="border-style:inset; width:150px; border-width:0.2em; border-color:gainsboro">

                    @if (@ViewBag.abc != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var i in ViewBag.abc) 
                        { 
                            @i
                        }
                    }
                </textarea>
               </td>
```

**Create Action**

```
public ActionResult Create(List<String> idlist)
    {
        string virgul = ",";
        ViewBag.virgul = virgul;

        if (idlist != null)
        {
            ViewBag.abc = idlist;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what your trying to do. You have invalid html - your checkboxes have duplicate `id` attributes so none of your scripts will work. Then your `.change()` function, the value of `id` will be `undefined` (its `val()` not `.value()`. Then you do an ajax post and in the controller method save put a value in `ViewBag` and try and redirect (ajax calls do not redirect) and as soon as the method exits, the `ViewBag` property is lost

Comment: Firstly I'm new about mvc and thanks your help.After your comment I change id to urunsec(checkbox id).But it doesn't work.I need to understand work this operating about checkboxlist-javascript-get values

Comment: Almost everything your doing with this code is wrong and makes no sense at all. Try and explain better what exactly your trying to achieve.

Comment: Okey,I explain step by step,
1-I'm making Bill application.And I need to input information of products.So I mark product that I want to add in another view(UrunList).
2-In UrunList view,I have a list of products.I need to mark I want by using checkboxlist.
3-So I want to set  value of checkboxs to Viewbag.abc by using parametre id(in script).And I send viewbag.abc as idlist to create action by using button.
@StephenMuecke

Comment: 4-I send value of idlist that was generated in button onclick to create action.Then this list is loaded viewbag.abc(ı guess this viewbag can have different name.)Finally I use last Viewbag in Create action

Note:I create bill in Create View
@StephenMuecke

Comment: Don't tell me what you think you are doing (nothing in your code works), instead describe what you want to do. (and edit the question - not in comments).

Comment: I wanna get checkboxlist selected value by using script and send this values another view.but I couldn't .You ask me general question so I answer general.You can ask more particularly.

Comment: You need to edit your question with the explanation, - we answer your question, not comments :)

Answer (score 0):

The same id may be a cause of this issue. You should try to assign different id (some unique value) to each element or you can try this:-

```
 @foreach (BillApplication.Models.Urunler con in Model )
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" name="urunsec" value="@con.UrunId.ToString()" onclick="ClickMe(this);" />
            <input name="urunsec" type="hidden" value="false" />
        </td>
        <td>@con.UrunId</td>
        <td>@con.UrunAdi</td>
        <td>@con.UrunFiyat</td>
        <td>@con.AltkategoriId</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>

}
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", new { idlist= @ViewBag.abc as List<String>})'" />

    </td>
</tr>

<script>

function ClickMe(ref) {
    var id=$(ref).value();
    $.ajax({
        url:'Fatura/UrunList',
        type:'POST',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function () {
            alert('suc');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error')
        }

     })
  }

 </script>
```

This should work with your case.

Comment: Unfortunately,nothing happen

Comment: have you checked your console for error? Is there any error in console?

Comment: Your breakpoint is reaching at UrunList() function. I mean the ajax is working fine?

Comment: No,becuse values is not sent UrunList()

Comment: you can alert(id) just before $.ajax and check that the value is coming or not. If the value is coming it means you have the Url path problem in your ajax. Please check.